# Word/phrase for a story in which time passes between scenes

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, literary-techniques

Stories like *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn* often have large time gaps between narration. Days, weeks, or even years might pass between chapters or scenes in stories such as these.

What word or phrase can be used to describe such a story?

Comment: Narratives written in sandwiched-lean-time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term is [***episodic novel***](http://fictionwriting.about.com/od/glossary/g/Episodic.htm). It means a story that consists of a sequence of mostly self-contained incidents, usually connected by the main character(s).